# ngrx/angular 6 - Trying to set params for action and another action through effect

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have a component that dispatches some UI actions, and for each of these UI actions, an ngrx store will be updated, and then the LoadData action called. Currently, each action looks something like this:

```
export class AddCityFilter implements Action {
  readonly type = ADD_CITY_FILTER;
  constructor(
    public payload: string,
    public loadParams: LoadParams
  ) {}
}
```

Here's an example of what one of the UI actions does in the store:

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case fromActions.ADD_CITY_FILTER: {
      const cityFilters = [...state.cityFilters, action.payload];
      return {
        ...state,
        cityFilters
      };
    }
```

and the effect that triggers the load action after any of these UI actions looks like this:

```
 @Effect()
 uiUpdate$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(
      uiActions.ADD_CITY_FILTER,
      uiActions.REMOVE_CITY_FILTER,
      uiActions.ADD_TYPE_FILTER,
      uiActions.REMOVE_TYPE_FILTER,
      uiActions.UPDATE_SORT_COLUMN
    ),
    map((action: uiActions.uiActions) => {
      return new opportunitiesActions.LoadOpportunities(action.loadParams);
    })
```

This is working, however, it bothers me that I have to pass the params for the loading action to the to initial action that updates the UI store. It feels wrong because those actions are intended for the UI store and shouldn't be aware of that next loading action ideally, and also because it forces me to add the loadParams property to an action that doesn't even need to pass anything (if I want to include it in the above effect). Is there a way to pass through the loadParams to the second load action without including them in the first UI action?

Comment: It sounds like you should be dispatching two actions...is there some reason you aren't?